# svelte.dev/repl does not appear to support indexedDb (or localStorage)

Tags: indexeddb, read-eval-print-loop, svelte

I tried a basic indexedDb connection within the Svelte REPL ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/569c0a7b1bcb416d939c9de58f57a307?version=3.22.2)) using the following code:

```
// test this code at https://svelte.dev/repl/569c0a7b1bcb416d939c9de58f57a307?version=3.22.2
if (window.indexedDB) {
    console.log("IndexedDB is supported");
}
else {
    alert("Indexed DB is not supported!");
}
// basic indexedDB API connections
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("AppDb", 1);
```

...however I receive the following error:

> Failed to execute 'open' on 'IDBFactory': access to the Indexed
>   Database API is denied in this context.

If I comment out the 'var openRequest...' line, the console prints "IndexedDB is supported" so this appears to be an issue with the REPL. Is this by design? It would be helpful to have indexedDb support in the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there are various security restrictions imposed on the REPL to prevent it being an XSS vector. Exposing a way to relax those restrictions on a per-app basis is a TODO!